# Shuffle Data from Dictionary for Test and Train Data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining

I want to split the data I have from a dictionary and a separate array into train and test data. I have tried various ways but am not getting there.  I need to keep the features as a dictionary initially due to how these are preprocessed in my pipeline. Anyone in the community have any suggestions for this?

**Dictionary (Feature Values):**

```
{'input1': array([42., 50., 68., ..., 60., 46., 60.]),
 'input2': array([[-2.00370455, -2.35689664, -1.96147382, ...,  2.11014128,
          2.59383321,  1.24209607],
        [-1.97130549, -2.19063663, -2.02996445, ...,  2.32125568,
          2.27316046,  1.48600614],
        [-2.01526666, -2.40440917, -1.94321752, ...,  2.15266657,
          2.68460488,  1.23534095],
        ...,
        [-2.1359458 , -2.52428007, -1.75701785, ...,  2.25480819,
          2.68114281,  1.75468981],
        [-1.95868206, -2.23297167, -1.96401751, ...,  2.07427239,
          2.60306072,  1.28556955],
        [-1.80507278, -2.62199521, -2.08697271, ...,  2.34080577,
          2.48254585,  1.52028871]])}
```

**Target Values**

```
y = array([0.83, 0.4 , 0.53, ..., 0.  , 0.94, 1. ])
Shape: (3000,)
```

**Creating the Dictionary**

```
#Dictionary Values
input1 = embeddings.numpy()
input2 = df['feature'].values
y = df['target'].values

full_model_inputs = [input1 , embeddings]
original_model_inputs = dict(input1 = input1 , input2 = input2 )
```

**Splitting the Data**

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split([original_model_inputs['input1'], 
                                                     original_model_inputs['input2']], y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 6)
```

*or*

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(original_model_inputs, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 6)
```

**Error Message**

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 3000]
```

**Input1:**

```
[55., 46., 46., ..., 60., 60., 45.]

Shape: (3000,)
```

**Input2:**

```
[[-2.00370455, -2.35689664, -1.96147382, ...,  2.11014128,
         2.59383321,  1.24209607],
       [-1.97130549, -2.19063663, -2.02996445, ...,  2.32125568,
         2.27316046,  1.48600614],
       [-2.01526666, -2.40440917, -1.94321752, ...,  2.15266657,
         2.68460488,  1.23534095],
       ...,
       [-2.1359458 , -2.52428007, -1.75701785, ...,  2.25480819,
         2.68114281,  1.75468981],
       [-1.95868206, -2.23297167, -1.96401751, ...,  2.07427239,
         2.60306072,  1.28556955],
       [-1.80507278, -2.62199521, -2.08697271, ...,  2.34080577,
         2.48254585,  1.52028871]]

Shape: (3000, 3840)
```

**Model Build**

```
input1= Input(shape = (1, ))
input2= Input(shape = (3840, ))

# The first branch operates on the first input
x = Dense(units = 128, activation="relu")(input1)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dense(units = 128, activation="relu")(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=x)

# The second branch operates on the second input (Embeddings)
y = Dense(units = 128, activation="relu")(input2)
y = BatchNormalization()(y)
y = Dense(units = 128, activation="relu")(y)
y = BatchNormalization()(y)  
y = Model(inputs=input2, outputs=y)

# combine the output of the two branches
combined = Concatenate()([x.output, y.output])

out = Dense(128, activation='relu')(combined)
out = Dropout(0.5)(out)
out = Dense(1)(out)

# The model will accept the inputs of the two branches and then output a single value
model = Model(inputs = [x.input, y.input], outputs = out)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer = Adam(lr = 0.001), metrics = ['mse'])

model.fit([X1,X2], Y, epochs=3)
```

Comment: What do those inputs look like? Are the dictionary arrays all the same size?

Comment: @yatu hey! yes they are all the same size. I just updated the question so you can see the actual inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your dictionary into a `pandas` df that will preserve data dimensionality and split as you desire:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"input1":original_model_inputs["input1"],  
                   "input2":list(original_model_inputs["input2"])})
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df,y)
```

Convert back to original format:

```
X_train = X_train.to_dict("list")
X_test = X_test.to_dict("list")
```

**Edit**

For your pipeline to stay functional you may need to add these 2 lines:

```
X_train = {k:np.array(v) for k,v in X_train.items()}
X_test = {k:np.array(v) for k,v in X_test.items()}
```

Comment: sorry for the delay in the response, was just trying to test some things out. Would it be possible to convert these values into a numpy array. "array" or something like this? instead of np.array(x_train['input1']) to access just one input from the dictionary.

Comment: All the values are accessible. These are exactly the same datastructures as you have as inputs. Can you be clearer what you can't achieve with the current solution? Example may be?

Comment: I just updated my post how I'm building the model, taking these two separate inputs. AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'. When I convert to numpy array, the model does work correctly. Sorry for the lack of clarification

Comment: model = build_model(np.array(x_train['input1']), np.array(x_train['input2'])) for example when I run the model with mentioned code in text.

Comment: thank you so much. This is working perfectly. I didn't think about this type of foor loop. Pretty neat!! I appreciate it :)

Comment: just did! sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

You're feeding a nested list as `X` when calling `train_test_split`, which raises the error. Instead you could build a 2D array of features from the dictionary, and then split into train and test. Take for instance:

```
d = {'input1': np.random.random((10,)),
     'input2': np.random.random((10,3))}
y = np.random.choice([0,1],10)
```

We can just add an axis if one of the arrays in the dictionary has a single dimension, and then concatenate the result into a 2D array:

```
X = [a[:,None] if len(a.shape)==1 else a for a in d.values()]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np.concatenate(X, axis=1), y)
```

Comment: Updated, should be fine now, thanks for letting me know @sergey

Comment: thanks for the answer,  I'm working with a muliple input ANN, so I need to separate the values. But this is a good direction for me to work in! so I appreicate it

Comment: I just updated my post how I'm building the model, taking these two separate inputs. Sorry for the lack of information and yes, I just upvoted :D